# Problems in installing jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I have installed jupyter notebook with pip through python and anaconda multiple times but I cannot find it in my start menu or any other location in my computer.

I have also tried using pip download and then pip install. It is successfull i cmd but I still cannot find it in my gui.

Comment: try typing jupyter-notebook in your python env

Comment: How about Jupyter lab?...Jupyter lab is similar to Jupyte notebook. It's hard to guess from here will be the issue. If you face the same with Jupyter lab then we will dig into it...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go about using Jupyter notebooks is to first create a conda environment that has `jupyter` installed. You can do this with the following line of code,

```
conda create -n my_env python jupyter
```

Optionally, you can even specify a python version as follows,

```
conda create -n my_env python=3.7 jupyter
```

Now, activate your environment,

```
conda activate my_env
```

Finally, launch Jupyter notebooks,

```
jupyter notebook
```

If you already have an environment created, just activate it, install `jupyter` and launch Jupyter notebooks,

```
conda activate my_env
pip install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```